# jQuery data() are lost if innerHTML is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand this. I have element ...

```
this.optionElement = $("<option />").text(this.name)
        .data('contact-detail', this);
```

... with some data stored with jQuery `data`

I append option to select. Later, I use `innerHTML` that removes select from html. And with that, jQuery data are lost for that option.

But the thing is, I still have reference to that select and also references to its options. So I can append select and options back in html. So I don't understand, why are data lost.

PS: Now I'm fixing this with `detach`, but it is annoying.

**EDIT:**

I really tried to reproduce my problem. Lot of things might not make any sence. My widget is larger and contains more object so...

http://jsfiddle.net/D5Gfc/6/

js:

```
// Object declarations
var Select = function (wrapper) {
    this.select = $("<select />");
    this.wrapper = wrapper;
    this.init();
};

Select.prototype.init = function () {
    this.select.change(this.onChange.bind(this));
    this.select.appendTo(this.wrapper);
};

Select.prototype.onChange = function () {
    var cDetail = this.select.find("option:selected").data("contact-detail");
    console.log("before html wipe:");
    console.log(this.select.find("option:selected").data());
    console.log(cDetail.option.data());
    this.wrapper.html("");
    this.wrapper.html(this.select);
    console.log("after:");
    console.log(this.select.find("option:selected").data());
    console.log(cDetail.option.data()); // in my code, this line still shows data
};

var ContactDetail = function (name, select) {
    this.select = select;
    this.name = name;
    this.init();
};

ContactDetail.prototype.init = function () {
    this.option = $("<option />").text(this.name).data("contact-detail", this);
    this.select.select.append(this.option);
};



// Part where I run widget
var list = ["phone", "blog", "email", "about"];

var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
var select = new Select(wrapper);

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    new ContactDetail(list[i], select);
}
```

Comment: When you use `innerHTML` (or, since you're using jQuery, `.html(newContent)` ) you're obliterating a part of the DOM; whatever was in the container previously will be gone.

Comment: @Pointy: But jQuery uses a `$.cache` variable to store `data` key/vals; it isn't actually kept on the DOM. Do you think the `data` still salvageable even if the DOM element is wiped?

Comment: Yes, it has that cache, but it will no longer be able to locate the element in the DOM. If you overwrite the DOM with `.html()`, the library will first call `.empty()` and I'm pretty sure that gets rid of anything in the data cache for the obliterated elements. If you want to keep the DOM nodes, then use `.remove()` or something.

Comment: @Pointy what is happening with the variable then? I though it points somewhere in DOM. Where `this.optionElement` points then?

Comment: It refers to a jQuery wrapper, not the DOM node. Now, after you've overwritten the DOM, I guess that the "orphan" DOM node is still referenced. Without seeing more of your code it's hard to say exactly what happens step by step.

Comment: @Pointy it refers to JQ wrapper which refers to DOM node. DOM node is not lost with `html`/`innerHTML`, if you still have reference. When I create element first, it is orphan too. It is out of html and data can be bind to it. Therefore I don't understand why are data gone, when it becomes orphan again. I provided more code as you requested.